# How to use the google sign in button assets

Tags: android, google-signin

I want to place a google sign in button in my cross-platform xamarin app.

I downloaded the assets from google and am confused as to how I'm supposed to use them...

In the android folder, there are assets for the various DPIs. But the problem is they all seem to have some weird black lines around them...

[image: google button]

What is the intended use of these lines? Am I supposed to crop them out?

Obviously I could just edit the files to my liking but I want to stay as true to google's usage policy as possible, and avoid altering another company's assets if possible.

I noticed that in the "web" folder there are complete buttons. So why would I use what's in the android folder?

How does google intend for developers to use these assets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I too have similar questions when trying to customise my Google Sign In buttons, and finally figured it all out after digging through the Android Documentation.

> What is the intended use of these lines?

The top and left lines define the area of the image that you are allowed to stretch, and the bottom and right lines define the area of the image that your text will occupy (see image below)

[image: Illustrate the use of lines]

> Am I supposed to crop them out?

No. Add this image into your drawable/res folder. Make sure you leave the .9.png extension as it is otherwise Android Studio won't adhere to the features mentioned previously!

> Why would I use what's in the android folder?

Great question! Because using this will make customising your app for different devices easier. To explain further, it is worth clarifying that:

- unlike any image assets, you will realise that this asset has a ***.9.png*** extension, suggesting that it is a [Nine Patch Drawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/NinePatchDrawable.html) Graphic
- it allows your text to fit nicely within the predetermined area, so it helps you to adhere to [Google's branding guidelines](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines#padding)

For more information, read [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch).

Hope this helps! Cheers.

Comment: Great Answer +1

Comment: This is a FANTASTIC answer. Thank you very much I sincerely appreciate the time you spent to help me out. This  addressed all of my concerns. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

Just use the batch drawable in android and edit the picture in ANDROID cropping out the image black lines.